# Docker swarm shared volume Mysql: Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-swarm, glusterfs

I've a cluster of 3 docker swarm nodes.
For each node I've created the directory */opt/dockershared/* and I've configured glusterfs to share this directory among the 3 nodes.

I"m trying to delpoy a stack of 4 services: NGINX Proxy, GUI, API, MYSQL

If I deploy the stack using the following yml there is no problem:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: my-nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "34200:34200"
    networks:
      - mynet

  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.6
    volumes:
      - MYDB:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "3306"
    deploy:
      restart_policy: 
        condition: any
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
     environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxx
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=db

  api:
    image: myapi:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /opt/dockershared/myapi:/data/tmp
    ports:
      - "3000"
    networks:
      - mynet
    deploy:
      restart_policy: 
        condition: any
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s

  gui:
    image: my-gui:latest
    ports:
      - "4200"
    networks:
      - mynet
    deploy:
      restart_policy: 
        condition: any
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s

networks:
  mynet:

volumes:
  MYDB:
```

As soon as I replace the volume **MYDB** in the *db service* with the folder shared with glusterfs (e.g. **/opt/dockershared/mydb:/var/lib/mysql**) I cannot connect anymore to mysql from my api service:

> Host 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

I haven't change the config of mysql, I've changed only the volume data dir. 
If I inspect the directory **/opt/dockershared/mydb**  I can see the default database created by MYSQL on the 3 nodes (test/, performance_schema/, mysql/, ib_logfile1)

What could be the problem?

thank you

Comment: I am getting kind of similar problem when trying to connect  to the mysql server running in one of the node